# Non Blocking timer that waits for 20 seconds before starting another timer

Tags: c++, linux, timer

I want to switch on a timer 20 seconds after the thread has started. How can i do this without blocking the execution.

So my thread entry function is ThreadInAction. I want to wait for 20 seconds before i start a timer from ThreadInAction, but i don't want to block this thread using sleep or anything.
How do we do that?

```
void* ThreadInAction()
{
     //code

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register a signal handler for SIGALRM like below.

```
sigaction(SIGALRM,struct_sigaction,NULL)
```

where `struct_sigaction` has a member `sa_handler` which will be pointing to your signal handler function.

Now create timer using the `setitimer` . Set the timer for 20 seconds.

Comment: > I am assuming you are working on a linux system. < Actually `setitimer` sets POSIX timer, so Unix systems support it as well as Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Create a first timer, that will generate a function call after 20 seconds and let this timer create the other timer.

Answer (score 1):

this little example should be reasonably portable.

Of course in a real application you'd want to do something more sensible than just print a message, and the main body of the thread would want to be getting on with some work (while perhaps polling an event so it knows when the timer has gone off).

Note that signals handlers are only called at specific points in your code - as a general rule you can assume they will interrupt system calls (in this case the underlying `nanosleep()` call in `std::this_thread::sleep_for`. However, to avoid surprises it's worth checking the documentation.

For an even more elaborate system of multiple high(ish)-resolution timers, there's the `setitimer` call exported from `sys/time.h`

Some reference links below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;


void alarm_handler(int i)
{
    cout << "alarm signalled " << i << endl;
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction alarm_action;
    memset(&alarm_action, sizeof(alarm_action), 0);
    alarm_action.sa_handler = &alarm_handler;
    alarm_action.sa_flags = 0;
    alarm_action.sa_mask = 0;

    sigaction(SIGALRM, &alarm_action, nullptr);
    alarm(2);
    cout << "waiting " << endl;

    auto t0 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(10));
    auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diff = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t1-t0);
    cout << "signalled after " << diff.count() << " milliseconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

controlling the action to take when timer is signalled:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html

signalling using an interval timer chain:
http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer

simple signalling with a scheduled alarm call:
http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) and the [`boost::asio::deadline_timer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html)

Comment: Though boost::asio timer callback is called asynchronously, you still need to call ioservice::run() for this to be invoked, which is a blocking call. If the application design restricts blocking calls, then ioservice::run() will have to be called on a separate thread.

Answer (score -1):

Your function must be doing something during this 20-second period or sleeping. If you don't want it to sleep, you can poll the time in a loop until the 20 seconds pass.

For example:
In the following code assume that `getTime()` returns the current time in milli-seconds (it may be the time passed since you started your computer or since a defined date and time).

```
#define TWENTY_SECONDS_PERIOD 20000

void* ThreadInAction()
{
   int initTime = getTime();
   while((getTime() - initTime) < TWENTY_SECONDS_PERIOD)
   {
      //do nothing
   }

   //your code
}
```

The equivalent of `getTime()` is some API supplied by your OS, library, or a standard library.

Comment: But i want my code to perform other tasks in that flow of execution rather than working on a logic to check if 20 seconds elapsed. That is i want it to execute my code or "//your code" part in those 20 seconds.

Comment: So I misunderstood your question